# spring integration migration 3 to 4 (JMS header issues)

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm in the process of migrating a web application from spring 3.1 to 4.1.  We use:

Framework,
Integration,
Batch,
Security,
and Web Services,

For the most part, it has been a relatively painless process; however, I am stuck on one issue with Integration.  This JMS message:

> GenericMessage [payload=com.etp.bpm.services.jaxwsbindings.data.ProcessActionInstance@50be7b46, headers={errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@98f5a14, jms_timestamp=1447280384929, determinantName=SeasonPeriod, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@98f5a14, processActionName=DerivationExecutionAction, jms_replyTo=HornetQQueue[asyncActionReplyQueue], jms_messageId=ID:4fd881ab-88c2-11e5-a7c1-a7dd640b56cc, timestamp=1447280384934, id=505ca511-88d0-e892-acdf-9bdc4330e68f, JMSXDeliveryCount=1, jms_redelivered=false, **priority=4**, determinantTypes=[Raw], jms_correlationId=e82424fd-3dab-4ef1-bad2-9a6ec7356a11_1, groups=[PrimaryDeterminantsGroup, 10 minutes, Weekly Prep Initial Settings]}]

is leading to this error:

> java.lang.Exception: The 'priority' header value must be an Integer.

When spring tries to verify the header value in org.springframework.integration.IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor, the error is thrown and later the process fails:

```
else if (IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER.equals(headerName)
                || IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_SIZE.equals(headerName)
                || IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.PRIORITY.equals(headerName)) {
            Assert.isTrue(Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(headerValue.getClass()), "The '" + headerName
                    + "' header value must be an Integer.");
        }
```

We don't have any JMS code in our application.  Spring creates and handles all the messages, so how it it creating a header it can't handle?

I thought it might be a version mismatch issue between integration, integration-jms, and jms-api, but I have all the correct jars in place.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.  (see stack trace below)

```
14:38:05,376 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8) java.lang.Exception: The 'priority' header value must be an Integer.

14:38:05,376 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.verifyType(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.java:109)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor.setHeader(MessageHeaderAccessor.java:308)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor.copyHeaders(MessageHeaderAccessor.java:393)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.copyHeaders(MessageBuilder.java:154)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.copyHeaders(MessageBuilder.java:42)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(JmsOutboundGateway.java:691)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:287)

14:38:05,377 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245)

14:38:05,378 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)

14:38:05,378 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150)

14:38:05,378 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)

14:38:05,378 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42)

14:38:05,378 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:79)

14:38:05,378 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:70)

14:38:05,378 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:321)

14:38:05,378 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:298)

14:38:05,378 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:414)

14:38:05,378 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:374)

14:38:05,378 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:365)

14:38:05,378 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.executeAsyncAction(Unknown Source)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterAdvice.java:43)

14:38:05,379 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)

14:38:05,380 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)

14:38:05,380 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

14:38:05,380 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)

14:38:05,381 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy232.executeAsyncAction(Unknown Source)

14:38:05,381 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at com.etp.bpm.actionservice.BaseActionServiceInvocationCommand.sendRequest(BaseActionServiceInvocationCommand.java:165)

14:38:05,381 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at com.etp.bpm.actionservice.AffinityCheckActionServiceInvocationCommand.executeCommand(AffinityCheckActionServiceInvocationCommand.java:94)

14:38:05,381 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at com.etp.bpm.command.AbstractDeferredBpmCommand.call(AbstractDeferredBpmCommand.java:82)

14:38:05,381 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at com.etp.bpm.command.AbstractDeferredBpmCommand.call(AbstractDeferredBpmCommand.java:1)

14:38:05,381 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy233.call(Unknown Source)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

14:38:05,382 INFO  [stdout] (Deferred Command #8)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier versions of the framework did not map the inbound priority.

This was added in 4.0 [JIRA here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3259).

```
headers.put(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.PRIORITY, jmsMessage.getJMSPriority());
```

According to [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSPriority()), it should be an `int`.

But it seems that HornetQ uses something else (not exactly sure how, given the API).

As a work-around, as @Artem said, you can filter it out, or set the `mapInboundPriority` property on the inbound header mapper to `false`. We added this boolean in anticipation of problems such as this.

[Documentation is here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-header-mapping).

Please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) so we can figure out exactly what HornetQ is setting it to. Or perhaps you can take a look in a debugger.

It could be a HornetQ bug.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It looks like someone upstream adds `priority` header but as a `Long`, not `Integer`.

That's why it stops to work. Nothing special around version mismatch.

Just scan your application for the `priority` word and try to figure out how to overcome it.

One of suggestion can be like `<header-filter header-names="priority">` just in front of `<int-jms:outbound-gateway>`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I did scan the app for 'priority,' but we are not setting the priority for any messages as far a I can tell.  How do you know the 'priority' header was added as a Long?

Comment: OK. IT might be even `String` :-). Doesn't matter. Anyway it isn't `Integer`. So, if it isn't yours header, than inbound external system provides it for you. E.g. `jms_replyTo=HornetQQueue[asyncActionReplyQueue]`. So, you really have some JMS stuff in your application...

Comment: @ArtemBilan - please see my answer. I guess I just have a memory for such things :)